# Polygon Buffer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, buffer

I am having trouble creating a buffer around a polygon of a county in QGIS. When I run the "fixed distance buffer" geoprocessing tool, no features are returned in the 'buffer' shapefile that is created. Has anyone had trouble with this as well? Or does anyone have suggestions of what I may be doing wrong?

Here is the polygon I am attempting to buffer:
[image]

Comment: Did you try to run the **Check Geometry Validity** tool? Corrupted geometries may cause this issue.

Comment: @mgri I just ran that tool and it only returned files with valid geometry, so it looks like there is no invalid geometry to be found within the shapefile..

Comment: Did you try with different parameters? Which ones you used, instead?

Comment: I used the "Check validity" under "vector geometry tools." There weren't any parameter options to select from. I am thinking that the problem may be that the polygon has internal enclaves, but I have been unable to dissolve those into the larger polygon so far.

Comment: I can't check it now, but I may have a look to your shapefile if you upload it. Is it possible?

Comment: That would be great! I'll attempt to upload it right now.

Comment: I'll check it tomorrow. Which distance and segments did you try?

Comment: Hey so I couldn't figure it out in QGIS (still), but I was able to perform the function in ArcMap. So the data was not corrupted- it seems like it will be a mystery why it didn't work. Thanks for your help though!